# Frameworks for smaller programs

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, frameworks, inversion-of-control

At my job, I am solely responsible for the development of small tools to solve problems for our customers. Most programs usually take more or less than a year to develop. But sometimes it's just a small tool that I develop in a month.

Today, I use the following framework for the development:

- [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)
- [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)
- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)
- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

I feel comfortable in this, but it is always possible to make things better. Sometimes I feel even a bit limited in what I can do.
It was a few years ago I took the decision to use these tools, and I guess it has happened a lot since then. What is relevant today? Can I safely continue working with them, or should I consider replacing any framework?
Or maybe expand my tool box with any additional framework?

Especially when I develop small applications, the frameworks are sometimes in the way, it becomes unnecessarily cumbersome. Do you have any good advice on how I can more easily develop small program that is still flexible.

Comment: The best answer is "reusability". If you keep consistent in your application structure, reusing framework may help you. Using these frameworks when starting a project from scratch may be overkill, but if the plumbing is already available, why don't reuse it? That said, MVVM light is.... light. I believe it's suited for all kind of projects. You can even go a step further by creating template projects, to quickly start new apps.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I used to try to reuse the building stone from previous projects. But I can certainly get better at it. Though, the building blocks must still be put together in any way, and that is where the frameworks are needed. Or?

Comment: I would recommend swapping out Ninject for something more lightweight if you don't want cumbersome libraries, something like SimpleInjector is just as easy to use but a lot lighter

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but I do not have the rep for that but:
I find for small, light tools that are meant to be simple and quick it is easier to build my own MVVM implementation. To get a proper MVVM structure you really only need a few things to get going, a good implementation of a base viewModel and a good way of navigating pages. Those frameworks generally do this and add more on top. If you don't need that extra functionality, it can just get in the way. Building your own allows you to keep it tailored to your needs and you can quickly reuse them when needed.